# Flutter checkbox: When I tick one element, all the others are getting selected too

Tags: android, flutter, dart, checkboxlist

In this portion of my code when I tick a element of checkboxlist all the others are also getting selected.

I tried on putting index on _State[index] ,but does not work.

```
FutureBuilder<List<Map>>(
future: fetchUsersFromDatabase(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment:    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[

              CheckboxListTile(

                  value:_State,
                  title: new Text(
                      snapshot.data[index]['checkcode'] +
                          ",Tk" +
                          snapshot.data[index]['amount'].toString(),
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0)),
                  activeColor: Colors.blue,
                  onChanged: (b) {
                    setState(() {                       
                     _State= !_State;
                    });
                  }),


              new Divider(),
            ],
          );
        });
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return new Text("${snapshot.error}");
    }
}
```

Expecting to select each element of list separately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using _state , try directly passing the value to the particular tile

```
onChanged: (bool value) {
    setState(() {
         widget.formItems[widget.count]['list'][i]['value'] = value;
    });
}
```

Comment: For checkboxList Widget it is mandatory to provide "value:" portion.

Answer (score 0):

Well your state object needs to be a list or map since you are working with list here. You can then initialize your `List<bool> _state` in `initState()` so first override that on your stateful widget then you will need such modification.

```
FutureBuilder<List<Map>>(
future: fetchUsersFromDatabase(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment:    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[

              CheckboxListTile(

                  value:_State[index],
                  title: new Text(
                      snapshot.data[index]['checkcode'] +
                          ",Tk" +
                          snapshot.data[index]['amount'].toString(),
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0)),
                  activeColor: Colors.blue,
                  onChanged: (b) {
                    setState(() {                       
                     _State[index]= !_State[index];
                    });
                  }),


              new Divider(),
            ],
          );
        });
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return new Text("${snapshot.error}");
    }
}
```